# Text never being set in controller when redirect occurs with struts

Tags: model-view-controller, struts2

I have been trying to learn angularjs/mvc/struts lately and I can't seem to get one last thing working on my application.

I have a struts folder an inside an actions.xml for all my struts that are related to actions.

Inside this I have a `HelloAction` class that gets a basic greeting to a string, I return success and it goes back to my action.xml to display the view - hello.jsp.

This is the link i use to get to my hello.jsp on localhost: `http://localhost:8080/application/hello.jsp`

Here is some code...

actions.xml

```
<action name="hello" class="com.testApplication.actions.HelloAction" >
    <result name="success">/hello.jsp</result>
</action>
```

HelloAction.java

```
package com.testApplication.actions;

import com.opensymphony.xwork2.Action;

public class HelloAction implements Action {

    private String greeting;

    @Override
    public String execute() throws Exception {
        setGreeting("Hello Struts 2");

        return "success";
    }

    public String getGreeting() {
        return greeting;
    }

    public void setGreeting(String greeting) {
        this.greeting = greeting;
    }

}
```

hello.jsp

```
<%@ taglib prefix="s" uri="/struts-tags" %>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

<title>Hello</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1><s:property  value="greeting" />!!!</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

My greeting is never being displayed though. I am able to render the page just no "Hello Struts 2"

Comment: Don't access jsp-s directly instead call an action. Try with `http://localhost:8080/application/hello`.

Comment: hmm, ding that gives me a 404,
type Status report

message There is no Action mapped for namespace [/] and action name [application/hello] associated with context path [].

description The requested resource is not available.

Comment: Remove `application` from the url if it isn't context path.

Comment: Now it says:  Unable to instantiate Action, com.testApplication.actions.HelloAction, defined for 'hello' in namespace '/'com.testApplication.actions.HelloAction

Root cause:
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:

Comment: Well the thing is, what I am trying to do is being added to a much larger application. Since I am learning, I do not completely understand all the moving parts yet. I do know that this applications web.xml is different than most of those I have looked at, considering they take upon a filter that passes org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter as the class, however the application's web.xml filter class is com.google.inject.servlet.GuiceFilter - guice. so I will have to dig into that first.

Comment: Well, it doesn't matter if you are getting `ClassNotFoundException`.